# What is this door furnishing called?

Tags: doors, furniture

I've been searching for the name of the part at the bottom of this door that's protruding outwards and diagonally on the sides, can anyone shed any light on this? I can't find the right term for it and it's exactly what I need to get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcXLx.jpg
[image]

Comment: Just looks like a piece of decorative trim, possibly covering a floor sweep.

Comment: It's a molding.

Answer (score 3):

It is a drip edge, it is usually applied on the outside face of a door that swings out. I have seen them on inswing doors too

There is no specific piece of molding for it in wood, but you can buy a metal door bottom with a sweep that has one integrated in with it. The ones of wood are simply a piece of molding or even flat stock with a sloped top attached to the face of the door at the bottom to direct the rain water over the threshold better